# Groovy, Grails & Eclipse/STS - Bad Version Number

Tags: java, eclipse, grails, groovy

I have a clean, vanilla system (Mac OS 1.5) with Java 6 installed - I have also installed the latest version of Grails (2.0.0.RC3) and STS (2.8.1), together with appropriate extensions:

- Grails Support
- Groovy 1.8 Compiler

Within STS I have navigated to Peferences -> Groovy -> Compiler and changed it to use version 1.8 compiler (rather than 1.7).

I have then created a blank Grails project from the command-line (using "grails create-app", etc) and everything works fine - I can compile/test/run it.

However, when I access the problem via STS/Eclipse I get a **Bad version number** being reported on **conf/ApplicationResources.groovy**; nevertheless, the project still works - I can still compile and run from within STS, but the auto-build feature keeps kicking in and reporting the same compilation problem on this file...

Can anyone shed any light on why this might be and how to solve it?

I have done various clean operations, such as "grails clean" and removed the **~/.grails** and **~/.groovy** directories in case of a stale class file, but it's made no difference so far...

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Managed to solve this via a clean install of STS - suspect that Eclipse had a cached class file that was compiled under a different JDK lurking somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

It seems my answer to Eclipse problems (not specific to STS) was usually do clean install.  You likely have already heard this and perhaps I should not post as an 'answer' (I'm new to stackoverflow) but my team uses IntelliJ IDEA across the board.  Some start with STS for familiarity but eventually that gets overridden by IntelliJ's Grails support.  It is worth giving it a try over Christmas break.  You can try the Ultimate edition (has Grails support) for free for at least 30 days and if you like, you can probably get an extension (I did for several months until my boss stepped up).

Answer (score 0):

Removed comment as issue returned